# How do I diagnose suspected radio interference from RF, Wifi and other radio devices?

Tags: wireless-networking

How would I diagnose suspected radio interference from RF, Wifi and other radio devices?

I'm using [wifi explorer](https://www.adriangranados.com/apps/wifi-explorer) on OSX which allows me to look at conflicting Wifi networks, but I suspect I've got some RF interference from a 3rd party that I'd like to explore.

Comment: I'd also love to know if there's a nice tool for this kind of thing - seeing interference which isn't necessarily wifi traffic, but on the same frequencies... Maybe SDR can do this, I've never looked deeply into it...

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: http://www.metageek.com/ but it's expensive.

Comment: What problems are you having, and what makes you think they're due to RF interference? I'm not being crabby here - the answers are key to selecting troubleshooting steps.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - we've got a 200mbps fibre line and a gigabit LAN, the wifi access point are rated at 300mbps throughput (half that to account for up/down, and then half again for real world environment) and we get about 70mbps over wifi (which is fine). The issue is this sometimes drops to 0.5 - 2mbps. I believe its due to interference as its intermittent, but not sure. When tested at the same time over a wired LAN its giving the full 200mbps, so i recon the issue is todo with the wireless signal.

Comment: What is the duration and frequency of the slowdowns? If you're not sure, I would set up a script to test it: copy a significant-sized file over the WiFi every x minutes (where x is short enough to likely encounter one of the slowdowns, say one quarter the duration of a typical slowdown), 24x7. Log the TOD and ET for each test and put the data into a spreadsheet. Once you find a suspect period of the day, increase the frequency of the tests during that time to get more fine-grained data. This info may be key to finding the source. (Are you sure it isn't just occasional, very heavy use?)

Comment: Does this happen both on 2.4 and 5 GHz channels? If only 2.4 and if only for short periods during the daytime, I would suspect a leaky microwave oven.

Comment: Currently the wifi access point we have is only 2.4ghz, we are going to upgrade to a dual band access point shortly, mainly to get more throughput over 2.4ghz. Re. microwave good idea but we dont have one in our office, funnily enough the first time i saw the issue was when i was working late one sunday so i dont think our office neighbours would have been in, incase they have a microwave. Will report back once the dual band AP is in, perhaps the 5ghz will be more resilient and all users are close enough to the AP to pickup 5ghz

Answer (score 2):

You want an RF spectrum analyzer that handles 2.4GHz and probably 5GHz as well. The Wi-Spy product line from MetaGeek is the cheapest I’m aware of.

Comment: If you're going to spend $500 or so on something you'll likely use only once, you'd likely be better off spending the money on a consultant, who will have a broadband spectrum  analyzer (not just the WiFi bands), directional antennas, and other specialized tools. Do the research I outlined above, like collecting info on precise times of day and duration of the problem, first, so as to optimize the consultant's time.